# function "scale_fill_fermenter" not working

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to run the following example code of function `scale_fill_fermenter()` from the ggplot2 reference.

```
#install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)
v <- ggplot(faithfuld) + geom_tile(aes(waiting, eruptions, fill = density))
v + scale_fill_fermenter()
```

But I got an error message: Error in scale_fill_fermenter() could not find function "scale_fill_fermenter()".

It's so strange since this is an example from the manual. Has anyone encountered the same problem? How did you solve it?

---

edit:

RStudio Version 1.2.5033

R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)

packageVersion("ggplot2")
[1] ‘3.3.0.9000’

Comment: Can you provide the link to this example ? I never heard about this function.

Comment: Here's the manual [https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_brewer.html](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_brewer.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the same problem by upgrading ggplot2. The latest version as I answer now is `3.3.1`.

Simply run `install.packages("ggplot2")` and restart the R environment.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
data(faithfuld)
library(ggplot2)
v <- ggplot(faithfuld) + geom_tile(aes(waiting, eruptions, fill = density))
v + scale_fill_fermenter()
```

Results in this plot for me.
[image: Plot]

Comment: Oh, it's strange. I just tried to create a reprex for the code in my question description and your answer, and both of them worked well - but I still cannot run the same code as a R script or rmarkdown chunk - so confused now. I find some applications that run R code online (like [this](https://rdrr.io/snippets/) and [this](https://rextester.com/l/r_online_compiler)) and they cannot run it either. I have a feeling that this problem is because of version difference, but not sure what exactly went wrong.